# INNER JOIN in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
const products = [{
    id: 5,
    productName: "Logitech Mouse",
    unitprice: 35
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    productName: "Logitech Keyboard",
    unitprice: 40
  }
];

const cart = [{
    id: 101,
    userId: 3,
    productId: 5,
    quantity: 2
  },
  {
    id: 102,
    userId: 3,
    productId: 6,
    quantity: 1
  }
];
```

With these data in the objects, how do I inner join cart's `productId` to product's `id`? So that the output will be :

Logitech Mouse, 35, 2
Logitech Keyboard, 40, 1

Comment: `cart.forEach(item=>item.product = products.find(product=>product.id === item.productId));` Done.

Comment: What do you mean with INNER JOIN in JS? There is no inner join. You want to solve this with usual code or are you using some library or database or something? You could use the comment above or for better performance us a map to store the values or use LINQ for JS. This would be more like SQL with JS: https://github.com/mihaifm/linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a more SQL like approach crating a hash table for the products and map cart with the wanted properties from the object from the hash table and `quantity`

As result, you get new objects with product name, unit price and quantity.

```js
const
    select = (keys, object) => Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, object[k]])),
    products = [{ id: 5, productName: "Logitech Mouse", unitprice: 35 }, { id: 6, productName: "Logitech Keyboard", unitprice: 40 }],
    cart = [{ id: 101, userId: 3, productId: 5, quantity: 2 }, { id: 102, userId: 3, productId: 6, quantity: 1 }],
    productsMap = products.reduce((r, o) => (r[o.id] = o, r), {}),
    result = cart.map(({ productId, quantity }) => ({ 
        ...select(['productName', 'unitprice'], productsMap[productId]),
        quantity
    }));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What if I just want the quantity directly from carts without any computation?

Comment: then you need to collect the totals first.

Comment: if I have only one object in my cart, it still print two rows

Comment: please see edit. it was not clear, which direction you had.

Answer (score 2):

*I will request you to try yourself first before **asking for help** to get the help from the community in the best possible way.*

You can try using [**`.map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [**`find()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) with [**Destructuring assignment**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const products = [{
    id: 5,
    productName: "Logitech Mouse",
    unitprice: 35
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    productName: "Logitech Keyboard",
    unitprice: 40
  }
];

const cart = [{
    id: 101,
    userId: 3,
    productId: 5,
    quantity: 2
  },
  {
    id: 102,
    userId: 3,
    productId: 6,
    quantity: 1
  }
];

var res = products.map(({id,...rest}) => {
  var cartObj = cart.find(c => c.productId == id);
  rest.quantity = (cartObj != undefined && 'quantity' in  cartObj) ? cartObj.quantity : 'N/A';
  return rest;
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Can explain a bit how ` rest.quantity = cart.find(c => c.productId == id).quantity;` works? I thought quantity is directly get from `cart` without any calculation?

Comment: @Steve, actually that statement is finding the object from the other array (*cart*) by matching the property value of *id* and *productId*, once found the object from cart, getting the property value of quantity which is assigned to *rest.quantity*:)

Comment: When there is only one object in `cart`, it throws error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'quantity' of undefined `